# "The process cannot access the file 'D:\dup.jpg' because it is being used by another process."

Tags: c#

Can anyone guide me in this issue..

How can i avoid this exception in VC# --

> "The process cannot access the file 'D:\dup.jpg' because it is being
>   used by another process."

Have a solution from Adi which doesnt worked out at all..

Snippet of Code is here ..

```
using (FileStream firstImageStream = 
    new FileStream(firstImage.FullName, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (FileStream secondImageStream = 
        new FileStream(secondImage.FullName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        hashingTool = new SHA256Managed();
        Byte[] imageOneHash = hashingTool.ComputeHash(firstImageStream);
        Byte[] imageTwoHash = hashingTool.ComputeHash(secondImageStream);
        hashingTool.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do to the file? Read or write to it?

Comment: It looks like read, `FileMode.Open`

Comment: I don't thing that there is problem with this part of code. Probably somewhere file is opened and not closed properly, do you any other parts whitch is working with this file too?

Comment: You can write this code in try catch block or open the file in shared mode.

Comment: I'll bet a buck that the same image is also being displayed in a picture box.  A nickel for the file names being the same.

Comment: ya.. am using the same image in picturebox too..

Answer (score 2):

You could try the `FileStream` constructor that takes `FileAccess` and `FileShare` parameters.

And specify, for example, `FileAccess.Read` and `FileShare.Read` to allow other processes (or your process) to open the same file for reading.

A shorthand for this is the `File.OpenRead` method:

```
using (FileStream secondImageStream = File.OpenRead(secondImage.FullName)) 
{
    ...
}
```

The current code is defaulting to write access (`FileAccess.ReadWrite`), and sharing for read access (`FileShare.Read`).  Hence two concurrent calls will conflict.

Comment: @Hans, updated to clarify this - the overload he currently uses requests write access - not the same as File.OpenRead.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first use [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) to figure out which process is locking your file. If it's not the process that you are compiling then you got your answer. If your own process is locking the file then put a break point at start of above code, run Handle at each stage to see when file gets locked.